# Unable to delete item from AWS-Amplify dynamoDB using GraphQL

Tags: react-native, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify-cli

I am new to react native, while delete item using aws-amplify graphql item is deleted from the table which is showing in content section but not from the dynamoDB table.

## Here is my code

```
export const delete_Template = async (newTemplate: any) => {
    console.log("newTemp=======", newTemplate)
    const temp = {
        id: newTemplate.id,
        template_name: newTemplate.template_name,
        userID: newTemplate.userID,
        _version: newTemplate._version,
        _deleted: newTemplate._deleted,
    }
    const updateTemp = new Templates(temp)

    const templateDetails: DeleteTemplatesInput = {
        id: newTemplate.id,
        _version: newTemplate._version
    };
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {

            const deleteTemplate = await API.graphql<GraphQLQuery<DeleteTemplatesMutation>>({ 
                query: deleteTemplates, 
                variables: { input: templateDetails }
              });
            
            resolve(deleteTemplate);
        } catch (e) {
            reject(e);
        }
    })
}
```

Let me know if anyone have appropriate answer how to delete item from dynamoDB table using aws-amplify graphql.